# How to make a function call with an array of characters in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, count, character

This is a program which display the number of words in a string.
I manage to make a function call but gives me an error of "Arguments list syntax error". 
Any answer would be a such great help.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int wordCount(char str[],int b);
    main()
    {
        char str[100];
        int b, d;
        clrscr();  // clear the screen every compile and build

        printf("Write your message: ");
        gets(str);   //reads the str[] which the user input
        b = strlen(str);  // run without the <string.h>

        d = wordCount(str,b);

        printf("No. of words: %d", d);

    getch();
    }

    int count(str[],b) // Where the error points out
    {
        int i=0,word=0;

        for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
        {
            if (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t')
            {
                word++;
                while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t')
                {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return word;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you *think* the `wordCount` function actually *is* ?

Comment: Using `gets()` is discouraged because it's not safe. If you have a modern compiler you should get a warning about that. Look at `fgets()`

Also, you need to include `<string.h>` to use `strlen()` in the intended way. The only reason it works is [For C, all undeclared functions are implicitly declared to return int and take an unspecified number of unspecified arguments.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21327973/6180573)

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify the type of your arguments in the function definition :

```
int count(str[],b){ ...
```

should become

```
int wordCount(char str[],int b){ ...
```

just like in your function declaration.

Plus, you have to specify the return type of `main()` -> `int main()`

Plus, you have to `#include <string.h>` to use `strlen()`

Comment: @kennethsantianez You should probably cast a glance at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes I made in your code, it will work now

```
#include<stdio.h>
int wordCount(char str[],int b);
main()
{
    char str[100];
    int b, d;
    clrscr();

    printf("Write your message: ");
    gets(str);
    b = strlen(str);
    d = wordCount(str,b);

    printf("No. of words: %d", d);

getch();
}

int wordCount(char str[],int b)
{
    int i=0,word=0;

    for (i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t')
        {
            word++;
            while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t')
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return word;
}
```

In your code, you didn't typed the correct function name as you have declared and the type of parameter was not given either thats why it was giving you error.

Comment: With `str[] == "abc"`, `while (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\t')  { i++; }` has no defined reason to stop looping.